# How to use randomTrue with Delay Block in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have a model where I need to introduce probability rate with Delay time.

50% Chance that the delay time will be 9 minutes
25% Chance that the delay time will be 18 minutes
25% Chance that the delay time will be 36 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways, here is one using conditional operators:
[image]

You can also create a function or use a table function or a custom distribution or ...